# Invalid character '\u0187' in ../plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to add `cordova-plugin-file` into my app, but after installing `cordova-plugin-file` when I start my application I got error message like this

```
!JavaScript ERROR: SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0187' on line 2 for http://localhost:49916/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: Error: Module cordova-plugin-file.FileWriter does not exist. on line 1371 for http://localhost:49916/ripple/cordova/cordova-3.5.0.js
```

when I open that `FileWritter.js` with Eclipse, I can't find that character, but when I open on browser whit that link on error message I can see the wrong Character.

this is the wrong character when I open with browser

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-file.FileWriter", function(require, exports, module) {
ï»¿/* //that is the wrong character
*
```

I've ready try to delete it but still not work.

What should I do to remove or solve this problem.

thank you,
**Regard,**